# Cached Layout file?

Tags: layout, magento-1.9.2.1, plugin

I have an issue, that i want to load an layout from a 3rd party module on a page in my module. I don't load the dependent layout explicitly, i just load my own:

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <myplugin_mymodule>
            <file>myplugin_mymodule.xml</file>
        </myplugin_mymodule>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

The Layout will (or should) be loaded by inheriting one Block of the 3rd-party module.

On my local machine it works all fine, but when i clone the same code on a pc of a colleague, it will not work, saying one block definition of the 3rd-party plugin is not loaded.

When i throw away my repository and clone the code fresh from the repository it works again fine.
The only difference now is the database and probably the cache files.

Or does someone got another idea regarding this?

**Edit - Regarding the comment about the Block:**

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();

    $stateBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_stateBlockName)
        ->setLayer($this->getLayer());
    $this->setChild('layer_state', $stateBlock);

    $this->getLayer()->apply();
    return $this;
}
```

I have the above code (in my Block) which is calling the _prepareLayout of the parent Block (from the 3rd-party plugin).
This will then do the layouting of the 3rd-party plugin.

Comment: *"The Layout will (or should) be loaded by inheriting one Block of the 3rd-party module."* <-- This sentence doesn't make sense in terms of layouts and blocks. Layouts contain blocks, not the other way around. Can you clarify?

Comment: I edited my comment, maybe its more clear now.